# Using jupyter notebook to run Javascript in vscode

Tags: javascript, python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

Looking for some guidance.  I have been using Jupyter notebooks fine in VScode (via installed extension) to run python snippets on Win10 box.  Python v3.38 correctly installed and is on windows system path.

Now I have been trying to create/run JavaScript notebook.
The instructions I found are:

1. npm install -g ijavascript
2. ijsconsole --version   (5.2.1, to verify)
3. Create a new Jupyter notebook; select code/cell to be javascript
4. Choose the appropriate *kernel* that should be Javascript

Problem is when I choose 'environment' I do not see Javascript as a choice nor can I type this in anywhere.  I am certainly missing a step somewhere.

Also, while inside vscode terminal/command prompt, if I type **jupyter notebook** I get the message:
'jupyter' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Although it does run fine within the IDE using the installed extension.

So again, for anyone who may have gotten this working, can you please share your steps.
Thanks!
Rob

Answer (score 0):

You can use iPython magic commands. With the cell language set to Python:

```
%%script node
```

Note: The `%%script` line is like the `#!` line of bash script, specifying a program (bash, perl, ruby, etc.) with which to run.